# Get parent index of rich:subTable

Tags: jsp, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

In my application I use a `rich:subTable` inside a `rich:dataTable`. I want to get the index of the `rich:subTable` inside the `rich:dataTable` when I click on a row of the `rich:subTable`. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the another approach that means using HtmlSubTable class of the subtable.

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery to get to the datatable row and then find the row index, 
something like this

var rowIndex = $(this).closest('tr').prevAll().length;

or

var row = $(this).parent().parent();
var rowIndex = $(row[0].rowIndex);